# Usage of unicode characters in URL

Tags: url, unicode, compatibility, non-ascii-characters

the base of this question comes from the fact that in many latin languages, and also in many non-latin languages there are letters that from what I've seen, up until recently were not really usable in URLs and nearly always ended up generating a big bunch of URL encoded characters.

But, recently I've seen several sites using native letters in URLs (except for domain).

Something like this for example using spanish accented letters:

```
https://www.example.com/esta-es-una-frase-en-español
https://www.example.com/cómo-usar-acentos-y-la-letra-ñ-en-urls
```

Also, I've seen URLs like

```
https://www.example.com/урл-на-български
```

From what I remember in terms of experience, not so long ago one had to either encode or convert accented characters to non-accented ones.

But now you can use this type of URL in the browser and it makes no issue and the letters appear as they should (not URL-encoded).

Is it safe to assume that now my URLs can handle these characters?

Also, is there any difference in terms of URL indexing for Google?

Comment: I assume you are using UTF-8 encoding, not latin1, UTF-16, etc.

Comment: I am specifically talking about URL characters, literally put in the browser's address line, as far as I know, the encoding of that would be either browser or OS related.

Answer (score 2):

URIs/URLs, as defined by [RFC 3986 "Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), do not allow *unencoded* non-ASCII characters.  Such characters must be charset-encoded (usually to UTF-8) and the resulting byte octets are then percent-encoded.  If a browser is given a URL with unencoded Unicode characters in it, the browser will typically url-encode it properly behind the scenes when transmitting it to a web server.  You can verify this with your browser's built-in debugger (if it has one) or an HTTP/S sniffer.

IRIs, as defined by [RFC 3987 "Internationalized Resource Identifiers (IRIs)"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987), do allow *unencoded* Unicode characters.  IRIs are not in widespread use yet, however IRIs can maintain backwards compatibility by mapping to/from encoded URIs/URLs.  It is possible that your browser may be treating the content of the address bar as an IRI, converting it to/from an URI/URL internally as needed.

Comment: Ok, so should there be a compatibility problem or I can use unicode characters freely? I did check in the network request and there it appears URL-encoded.

Comment: You can use Unicode characters in a browser address bar, they will likely get encoded for you. But you can't use *unencoded* Unicode characters in your own URLs, no.

Comment: I do not completely understand what you mean by this. You are saying that if I write `https://www.example.com/señor` that would work, but if I create an html link with the same URL it won't?

Comment: @MihailMinkov yes, that is what I'm saying.

Comment: But the thing with that is that I AM generating links so, the link is something like `<a href="https://www.example.com/si-señor">Spanish Link</a>` and when I click on it, the route I have defined for this works. I am using CodeIgniter 4.

Comment: "Legal". It is allowed. Many Wikipedia pages have such URL, and use such anchor. Just Browsers will escape URL for HTTP, and often they do the same on reverse. For sure there is also a W3C document for that.

Comment: in fact:  https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/

Comment: So, @GiacomoCatenazzi supposedly it is usable and compatible? Is there a way to check compatibility? Something like caniuse.com? I checked there, but it doesn't appear.

Comment: @MihailMinkov: That document tall us "The conversion process for parts of the IRI relating to the path is already supported natively in the latest versions of IE7, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Google Chrome.". Server side may have more problem. Wikipedia is using it since a lot of time (so I assume it is safe)

Comment: Could you post this as an answer @GiacomoCatenazzi ?

Answer (score 0):

What Google says ([reference](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/url-structure)):

> Recommended: Use UTF-8 encoding as necessary.

And:

> Not recommended: Using non-ASCII characters in the URL

Google wants you to encode the URLs in the anchors, yet you are free with the title of the anchor.

As you have mentioned Wikipedia, all URLs in the anchors are in fact encoded, but of course the browsers and their servers handle the encoded URLs. Attached example from Wikipedia:

[image]